# How to Seperate or Extract HTML Tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visual-studio-code, notepad++

.

**I am looking for extract HTML elements (tags) from a HTML file.
For eg:**

```
<div id="collapse" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"></div>
<div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
<ul>
    <liLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</li>
    <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="controlAccount" id="controlAccount" class="input" value="1">
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="">SUBMIT</button>
```

**I need a result like this;**

```
<div id="collapse1" class="collapse"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<p class="text"></p>
<p></p>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="list"></li>
</ul>
<input id="controlAccount" class="input">
<button class="slick-prev slick-arrow"></button>
```

**I want to keep only IDs and Classes in the HTML file.**
**Is it possible ? You know any website or easy method or any software ? Any addon for *Visual Studio code OR Notepad++* ?**

.

Comment: So copy the elements, remove the textContent, and strip the data and aria attributes?

Comment: Yes Sir.. Result like this: https://prnt.sc/tawe6l

Comment: Keeping only IDs and Classes in HTML tags. Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/tawe6l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you want to copy only the structure with the appropriate tag names, ids, and classes.

One way you can so this is to build a tree that represents the HTML. After that, you can render new HTML from it. If you want to adapt this, you will need to read the file in and add it to the DOM, to treat it like actual HTML, then you can describe, and render the altered HTML. This is just a trivial example.

You essentially want to do the following:

```js
const main = () => {
  let root = document.body
  let tree = describeHTML(root)
  let html = renderHTML(tree)
  console.log(html.innerHTML)
}
```

```js
const main = () => {
  console.log(emptyInnerHTML(document.body))
}

const emptyInnerHTML = (element) => {
  return renderHTML(describeHTML(element)).innerHTML
}

const describeHTML = (node) => {
  return ({
    tagName: node.tagName,
    id: node.id || undefined,
    classList: [...node.classList],
    children: [...node.childNodes]
      .filter(child => child.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE && child.tagName !== 'SCRIPT')
      .map(child => describeHTML(child))
  })
}

const renderHTML = (tree) => {
  let node = document.createElement(tree.tagName)
  if (tree.id) node.setAttribute('id', tree.id)
  if (tree.classList && tree.classList.length) node.className = tree.classList.join(' ')
  if (tree.children && tree.children.length) {
    tree.children.forEach(child => node.appendChild(renderHTML(child)))
  }
  return node
}

main()
```

```html
<div id="collapse" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"></div>
<div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="controlAccount" id="controlAccount" class="input" value="1">
<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="">SUBMIT</button>
```

#### Output

```html
<div id="collapse" class="collapse"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<p class="text"></p>
<p></p>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="list"></li>
</ul>
<input id="controlAccount" class="input">
<button class="slick-prev slick-arrow"></button>
```

#### Tree View

```
{
  "tagName": "BODY",
  "children": [
    {
      "tagName": "DIV",
      "id": "collapse",
      "classList": [ "collapse" ]
    },
    {
      "tagName": "DIV",
      "classList": [ "card-body" ]
    },
    {
      "tagName": "P",
      "classList": [ "text" ]
    },
    {
      "tagName": "P"
    },
    {
      "tagName": "UL",
      "children": [
        {
          "tagName": "LI"
        },
        {
          "tagName": "LI",
          "classList": [ "list" ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tagName": "INPUT",
      "id": "controlAccount",
      "classList": [ "input" ]
    },
    {
      "tagName": "BUTTON",
      "classList": [ "slick-prev", "slick-arrow" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great sir.. Is it Jquery? I am not good in Javascript and Jquery

Comment: @WellWisher this is as vanilla as you can get in JS, keep in mind that this is ES6 code, but it will run in Chrome and FF with no problems. There is practically no need for jQuery anymore, unless you need plugins, UI dragging, or CSS animations. jQuery used to be used a lot when IE was still around for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.. I will make it as answered. You are an excellent developer. I am not good in Javascript and Jquery. Could you show in JSfiddle OR Codepen ?

Comment: @WellWisher The code snippet runs just like JSFiddle. All you need to do is click "Run code snippet" to see it in action. If you really do not understand JS, you will need to study the language first, to get a grasp on it, before truly understanding this code. The code above is not advanced at all. It is just simple recursion and knowing how to read the DOM, and build a DOM using JavaScript. Start with reading the docs on the MDN site e.g. [`Document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Thank you sir..  I maked your answer as answered. https://prnt.sc/tax4o2

Comment: @WellWisher well, if you have any future questions, be prepared to provide runnable code and a meaningful explanation of what is wrong with the code, and how to mitigate the issue. Be sure to read up on [_"How do I ask a good question?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)